# What is the currently the preferred location of PowerShell profiles?

Tags: powershell, profile

I've come across this (archived) [Blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) on PowerShell profiles. In the [learning docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.4) I read a note that the scripts should not be stored on OneDrive. Users probably will use the standard settings of OneDrive backing up Documents, Desktop and Pictures to OneDrive. I'm quite confused now. Are these locations in blog and learning still accurate as of 2024?

What location should I use for what type of scripts or modules?

Comment: The best location is anywhere that OneDrive does not sync. The default is Documents, so either set it to somewhere else, or don't backup your documents, but rather move the files in Documents manually to your OneDrive, and place a link to it in your documents.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you have found is from 2012 and refers to an
older version of Windows. While most of it is still correct,
the profile folders are not up to date.

The article you found is more recent from 2023, so is to be
taken seriously.
The "Current user, Current Host" profile location is said to
be in `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell`, which refers to
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\Documents\PowerShell`.

If you install OneDrive, it will by default backup the
`Documents` folder, by relocating it into the OneDrive
sync folder and leaving only a pointer to it in
`C:\Users\USER-NAME`.

This means that, if you have accepted the default setup of
OneDrive, your PowerShell profiles are by default synced
to OneDrive, but your reference is to a local folder.
The profiles will be backed up to OneDrive, but the
reference should stay to the local disk, not to the
OneDrive folder in the cloud, to avoid problems when
there is no internet connection.

Comment: This is not true, and I speak of a horrible experience. Yes, powershell's profile is the documents folder, but if you allow OneDrive to backup the Documents, not only will it move everything to the OneDrive, the powershell profile will be moved there too, and this is a big issue as powershell now becomes really slow with things like autocomplete and starting up. So the last paragraph about the reference is a local folder and its only a backup is not correct.

Comment: The biggest problem is that OneDrive keeps a lock on the file like a virus scanner on overdrive.